# gql inside transactions

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Google app engine returns "BadRequestError: Only ancestor queries are allowed inside transactions." What does this mean in the context of code:

```
class Counter(db.Model):
        totalRegistrations = db.IntegerProperty(default=0)   

@db.transactional
def countUsers():
    counter = Counter.all().get()
    counter.totalRegistrations = counter.totalRegistrations + 1
    counter.put()
    i = counter.totalRegistrations
    return i

print countUsers()
```

Comment: Note that what you're doing is a sort of anti-pattern: By having a single entity you need to update, you're limiting callers to this code to about 1QPS. Also, you should use key names to avoid the need for the query in the first place. Also, never, ever use `print` in a webapp.

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks for the comment. Can you please explain what you mean by 'use key names to avoid the need for a query'. I understand this code would create a GAE bottle neck, but how did you come up with the 1QPS limitation? Thank you.

Comment: If you only have a single counter, you can specify a key name when you create it. THen, use `Counter.get_by_key_name` inside the transaction with the name you specified, avoiding the need for a query. The 1QPS limit is the documented lower bound on the number of transactions you can expect to be able to do on a single entity group. Introducing this sort of bottleneck into your app is a Very Bad Idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It simply means that the query you run with `Counter.all().get()` is not an ancestor query. In this case, you should take the query that fetches the counter out of the transactional method, like this:

```
@db.transactional
def incrementUsers(counterKey):
    counter = Counter.get(counterKey)
    counter.totalRegistrations = counter.totalRegistrations + 1
    counter.put()
    return counter.totalRegistrations

counterKey = Counter.all(keys_only=True).get()

print incrementUsers(counterKey)
```

This means you first get a reference to the Counter, but only get and put the value in the transactional method, guaranteeing atomicity.